# How to build a standalone executable script from an Nx project?

Tags: node.js, webpack, compilation, nomachine-nx

I have an Nx project that has a backend module that I'd like to deploy. My problem is that after compilation the `node_modules` folder becomes **huge** and Heroku rejects my deployment.

I tried deleting the `node_modules` folder because I thought that after compiling the project I'm not gonna need it anymore.

What happened after I ran `node main.js` was this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'
Require stack:
- /dist/apps/backend/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.752 (/dist/apps/backend/main.js:2:898496)
    at __webpack_require__ (/dist/apps/backend/main.js:2:898874)
    at /dist/apps/backend/main.js:2:899067
    at /dist/apps/backend/main.js:2:899812
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dist/apps/backend/main.js:2:900044)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/dist/apps/backend/main.js' ]
```

As it turns out this `main.js` that I've compiled *(with Webpack)* still needs some external dependencies.

**How can I configure a compilation that does not need `node_modules`?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't run your project without the node_modules.
When you run your app, you need to have the node_modules at the root path and your dist folder.
It should look like this :

```
- dist
- node_modules
```